# PriorityQueues, custom classes, and the Comparable interface

Tags: java, priority-queue, comparable

I have the following class.

```
private static class Node {
    public int id; // 0 indexed
    public int distFromS;

    Node(int id, int distFromS) {
        this.id = id;
        this.distFromS = distFromS;
    }
}
```

I'm storing instances of `Node` in a `PriorityQueue` and manipulating them...

```
PriorityQueue<Node> procQueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
int[] distsFromS = new int[n];
Arrays.fill(distsFromS, -1);
// Read in s, add to processing queue
int s = (in.nextInt()) - 1; // 0 indexed
procQueue.add(new Node(s, 0));
// While queue isn't empty
while (procQueue.size() > 0) {
    // deque "curr". If we haven't already reached curr from s
    Node curr = procQueue.remove();
    if (distsFromS[curr.id] == -1) {
        // record distance.
        distsFromS[curr.id] = curr.distFromS;
        // enqueue all children of curr. distFromS = curr.distFromS + 6                    
        Iterator<Integer> itr = edges[curr.id].iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            procQueue.add(new Node(itr.next(), curr.distFromS + EDGE_WEIGHT)); // ***Exception is here***
        }              
    }              
}
```

But I'm getting the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Solution$Node cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUpComparable(PriorityQueue.java:652)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.siftUp(PriorityQueue.java:647)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.offer(PriorityQueue.java:344)
    at java.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:321)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:52)
```

Do I need to implement `compareTo` for `Node`? Why? As far as I can tell I'm not doing any comparisons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to make your class Node implement Comparable

```
private static class Node implements Comparable<Node> {

    public int id; // 0 indexed
    public int distFromS;

    Node(int id, int distFromS) {
        this.id = id;
        this.distFromS = distFromS;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node another) {
        // your codes here
    }
}
```

or give a Comparator when constructing the PriorityQueue

```
PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<>(new Comparator<Node>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
        // your codes here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

> An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used. A priority queue does not permit null elements. A priority queue relying on natural ordering also does not permit insertion of non-comparable objects (doing so may result in ClassCastException).

You need to either specify a comparator or you class needs to be comparable.
Otherwise the `PriorityQueue` has no way of knowing which objects take priority.

Comment: Are there any `Queue` implementations that don't enforce an ordering? I don't need that feature, and would prefer not to implement the comparator stuff.

Comment: @Adam what do you think "priority" means? And since you appear to be implementing something like Dijkstra's algorithm, are you sure you don't need to get the nodes in a particular order?

Comment: @AndyTurner. Yes, I'm sure they don't need to be ordered. The edge weights are constant in this problem.

Comment: To be more precise, I should say they're all the same value.

Comment: @Adam Most queue implementations are first-in-first-out. Have a look through the implementations: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you need to implement comparable.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#add(E)

throws

> ClassCastException - if the specified element cannot be compared with
>   elements currently in this priority queue according to the priority
>   queue's ordering